# Dynamically Naming Sections of Columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I am doing calculations that change how much of the data I want to include in a graph for each data set. I have cells that reference the first and last row numbers that I need to use and then I have a graph that will plot the X and Y axis based on the automatically updating columns.

I have tried using offset and indirect while defining a column name but it has not worked:

```
OFFSET($H$5, 0, 0, COUNT(INDIRECT(Y46&":"&Y47)), 1))
```

Where Y46 contains the text "H5" and Y47 contains "H318" (Y46 and Y47 are the cells that already automatically update based on the data).

I am using Excel 2016.

UPDATE:

I can dynamically name my ranges using either of the following codes:

```
OFFSET('VIC 3D Data'!$M$5,0,0,COUNT(INDIRECT('VIC 3D Data'!$AB$46):INDIRECT('VIC 3D Data'!$AB$47)),1)


INDIRECT('VIC 3D Data'!$AB$46):INDIRECT('VIC 3D Data'!$AB$47)
```

When I select them in the name manager the correct cells are highlighted, however, when I try to plot them in my graph it says: "Excel found a problem with one or more formula references in this worksheet. Check that the cell references, range names, defined names, and links to other workbooks are correct"

Any ideas?